# Insert constant value in table using sql script

Tags: mysql, sql

I am transferring data from one table to another table using sql script. In my parent table I have certain columns which have constants declared. I want that, instead of transferring the constant's *value*, their *name* should be transferred instead. Is it possible using sql script?

**PARENT TBL**

```
ID | NAME | COLOR_ID
2  | test | 1
```

I just want `color_id` to be changed to Green via sql script.

**RECEIVING TBL**

```
ID | NAME | COLOR
2  | test | Green
```

**Script**

```
Insert in receiving_tbl(id, name, color) select (id, name, color_id) from parent_tbl
```

Comment: Where is the information that 1 = Green?

Comment: @Serpiton Yes, 1= Green, 2=Red etc.

Comment: Where the color name are defined? There is another table I think

Comment: @Serpiton This is the problem, they are application constants but i want them to be transferred as name to other table. Certainly, i would be required to declare them but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the color name are not defined in the database the only option is to define a `CASE` to translate the ID to the names, something like

```
INSERT INTO receiving_tbl(id, name, color) 
SELECT id, name
     , CASE color_id WHEN 1 THEN 'Green'
                     WHEN 2 THEN 'Red'
                     ...
                     ELSE NULL
       END 
FROM parent_tbl
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a table with your color ids and names stored, you can do this easily by including a join to your "name" table.

If, however, you do not have this information stored in a table, you can create this type of logic by using a [case statement](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-statement/).

```
CASE  case_expression
   WHEN when_expression_1 THEN commands
   WHEN when_expression_2 THEN commands
   ...
   ELSE commands
END CASE;
```